# jQuery UI Autocomplete last option exceeding height

Tags: css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.12.1 for several dropdowns, with some having a lot of options.  In order to accommodate scrolling, we added the following into our stylesheet:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 180px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1002;
}
```

What's happening now is that when you mouseover the last option in shorter lists, it triggers the vertical scrollbar as in the images below:

[image: Normal dropdown]

[image: Rollover last option]

My suspicion is that the element height/width that is calculated by the library is missing 2 pixels somewhere, perhaps from the border?  Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the problem, we used two separate css classes - one for the case of a dropdown that needed a scrollbar and one for a dropdown known to have only a few options.